# In coded ui how do you correctly retrieve a browser window that contains an embedded Adobe PDF reader in browser

Tags: c#, multithreading, coded-ui-tests

I'am running across this issue when I'm debugging or running my coded UI automation project, where i get the exception labeled "{"COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used." System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException}" everytime i come from a browser window that contains a pdf reader embedded in it. This happens every time I retrieve the window and try to click back.  It barfs when i perform the back method on it. I've tried different things but none has worked including the playback wait.

```
var hereIsmypdf = ReturnPDFDoc();

   public BrowserWindow ReturnPDFDoc()
    {
        Playback.Wait(1000);

        var myPdFdoc = GlobalVariables.Browser;      

        return myPdFdoc;
    } 

hereIsmypdf.Back();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i was able to get around this issue was not to use the BrowserWindow class.  I ended up using the WinWindow class and just getting the tab of the window from it.  The BrowserWindow class seemed to trigger the exception "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used." System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException}" everytime i tried to retrieve it.  I hope this helps someone one or maybe someone has a better way to handle this issue.

For the people that voted my question down, i really did try to figure it out. Sorry i wasnt clear about what i was asking the community or couldn't properly articulate what this pain was. I'm sure someone probably is going through the same pain i did and having a hard time articulating whats going on.

Here is my code on what i ended up doing

```
public WinTabPage ReturnPDFDoc()
    {
        WinWindow Wnd = new WinWindow();
        Wnd.SearchProperties[BrowserWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "IEFrame";

        WinTabList tabRoWlist = new WinTabList(Wnd);
         tabRoWlist.SearchProperties[WinTabPage.PropertyNames.Name] = "Tab Row";

        WinTabPage myTab = new WinTabPage(tabRoWlist);
        myTab.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        myTab.SearchProperties[WinTabPage.PropertyNames.Name] = "something";
        //UITestControlCollection windows = newWin.FindMatchingControls();


        return myTab;
    }
```